# Mysql trigger to get data from another table and update after insert

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have two tables one with inventory and other one is scanned inventory items.

```
Inventory table with (ID,Barcode,Model,Brand,Machine_type)
Scanned table with (ID,Barcode,Machine_type)
```

Here is what i need

When someone insert barcode into scanned table it should update scanned table machine_type from inventory table barcode.

[image]

Comment: When someone is able to store `Barcode` into scanned table, they should able to store `Machine_type` as well. Or you did not check the inventory and let someone simply store `Barcode` as they like?

Comment: You must do this in BEFORE trigger. Get according value then set NEW.Machine_type to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_Scanned
BEFORE INSERT ON Scanned
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.Machine_type = (
    SELECT Machine_type
    FROM Inventory 
    WHERE Barcode = NEW.Barcode
    );
```